# Why is a transformer hooked up to a 480v 208/120 experiencing voltage drop on the secondary side?

Tags: transformer, output

[image: secondary]I'm experiencing some pretty drastic voltage drop on the output of a transformer as well. 480v 208/120v across the phases I'm getting 210 and phase to ground 80, 84 and 94. Just beginning to look for answers, should I replace the transformer. I am getting these voltages even with no load connected. 480 delta on primary side and I think 208/120 Y on secondary, it is an old install on a cnc robodrill. There is an X0 terminal but only x1,x2 and x3 are wired up. It has a ground. No other info available.

Comment: It is a 15kva Transformer hooked up to an older cnc robodrill with fanuc drives, that started giving low voltage errors. Using a meter reading phase to phase voltage X1 to X2 and X3 is reading 210v to 209v respectively across the phases and X1 to ground is 80v, X2 to ground is 84v and X3 to ground reads 94v the tag on it is to worn to read. There is no neutral hooked up and it has a ground. The paperwork in the panel says it's a 15kva but nothing else.

Comment: Please add the details into your question (rather than in comments) and draw a schematic of what you have. A data sheet for the transformer would be quite useful too.

Comment: I'm sorry but none of that information is available. I can only assume because it has an x1, x2, x3 and an unused x0 that it is a y configuration but not wired that way and it's been in operation for many years from what I'm told. Still searching for other information.

Comment: Please measure x1/2/3 to X0 and X0 to ground.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The voltages should measure as follows:

1. L1L2 = L2L3 = L3L1 = 480 V
2. X1X2 = X2X3 = X3X1 = 208 V
3. X1X0 = X2X0 = X3X0 = 120 V

It's not correct to take measurements between X1, X2, X3 and earth. They would have read 120 V had the neutral been earthed.

Comment: I agree but in an imdustrial.emvironme t such as the one I'm currently in there are several machines that have been in operation like this for 30 plus years with transformers not using x0 and only wired to x1x2 and x3. They are showing 220v x1,x2 and x1,x3 and x2, x3 with no x0 tap and measuring to ground x1 120v, x2 120v and x3 140. I didn't wire these setups its just what I'm faced with at the moment. There is a control transformer in the machine supplying 120 for controls. Thanks.ill try and find more info elsewhere. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Hi Eric, The neutral  X0 need not be wired should single-phase 120 V supply not be required.

Comment: Thanks,.ya they derive control voltages by using a separate transformer in the cnc. Its just weird that these old cnc machines operate on 220v supply and the only issue I can see causing the low voltage errors is the transformer which led me to try and find a reason for this drop in secondary voltage. I've already ordered a new transformer with the intent of replacing this one. I was just trying to find out what might cause the transformer to drop voltage on the secondary side. Thanks all for any replies.

Comment: Think I figured it out, it isnt the main transformer at all but the secondary buck boost transformer boosting the voltage from 208 to 220. Thanks all. Thats what I get for not thinking it through. Have a nice rest of your day.

Comment: Hi Eric, I'm glad you figured it  out. Many thanks and have a nice day too!